# Issue installing R package 'devtools' in Docker - getting error installing git2r

Tags: r, docker, miniconda

I am using a continuumio/miniconda3:latest base container and activating a Conda environment.
This all works fine.

When I run:
`RUN R -e "install.packages('devtools',repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"`

I get an error:

```
configure: Package dependency requirement 'libgit2 >= 0.26.0' could not be satisfied.

  -----------------------------------------------------------------------

   Unable to find the libgit2 library on this system. Building 'git2r'
   using the bundled source of the libgit2 library.

   To build git2r with a system installation of libgit2, please install:
     libgit2-dev   (package on e.g. Debian and Ubuntu)
     libgit2-devel (package on e.g. Fedora, CentOS and RHEL)
     libgit2       (Homebrew package on OS X)
   and try again.

   If the libgit2 library is installed on your system but the git2r
   configuration is unable to find it, you can specify the include and
   lib path to libgit2 with:

   given you downloaded a tar-gz archive:
   R CMD INSTALL git2r-.tar.gz --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=/path/to/include LIB_DIR=/path/to/lib'

   or cloned the GitHub git2r repository into a directory:
   R CMD INSTALL git2r/ --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=/path/to/include LIB_DIR=/path/to/lib'

   or download and install git2r in R using
   install.packages('git2r', type='source', configure.vars='LIB_DIR=-L/path/to/libs INCLUDE_DIR=-I/path/to/headers')

   On macOS, another possibility is to let the configuration
   automatically download the libgit2 library from the Homebrew
   package manager with:

   R CMD INSTALL git2r-.tar.gz --configure-vars='autobrew=yes'
   or
   R CMD INSTALL git2r/ --configure-vars='autobrew=yes'
   or
   install.packages('git2r', type='source', configure.vars='autobrew=yes')

  -----------------------------------------------------------------------


configure: Attempting configuration of bundled libgit2
checking size of void*... 8
checking for library containing inflate... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/Rtmpbkmfhr/R.INSTALL8c407eb001/git2r':
configure: error:
  ---------------------------------------------
   The zlib library that is required to build
   git2r was not found.

   Please install:
     zlib1g-dev (package on e.g. Debian and Ubuntu)
     zlib-devel (package on e.g. Fedora, CentOS and RHEL)
   and try again.

   If the zlib library is installed on your
   system but the git2r configuration is
   unable to find it, you can specify the
   include and lib path to zlib with:
   R CMD INSTALL git2r --configure-vars='LIBS=-L/path/to/libs CPPFLAGS=-I/path/to/headers'
  ---------------------------------------------
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘git2r’
* removing ‘/opt/conda/envs/r-app/lib/R/library/git2r’
```

I have libgit2-dev installed at the start of my Dockerfile using `apt-get install libgit2-dev` and it installs libgit2 version 0.27.7.

Now the odd part about this is if I start the container and access it, I can run the `"install.packages('devtools',repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"` just fine and it works.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3:latest

RUN apt-get update -y; apt-get upgrade -y; \
    apt-get install -y vim ssh libgit2-dev zlib1g-dev \
    build-essential gcc gfortran g++

RUN conda update -n base -c defaults conda
COPY environment.yml environment.yml
RUN conda env create -f environment.yml

RUN echo "source activate r-env" >> ~/.bashrc

ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/r-env/bin:/opt/conda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

RUN R -e "install.packages('devtools',repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
```

environment.yml:

```
name: r-env
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.7
  - r-essentials
  - r-base
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the last line of your Dockerfile with:

```
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('devtools',repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
```